# Woocommerce add product to cart with variation id

Tags: woocommerce

all. Please give some help to me, i am a bit newbie in woocommerce mechanics.
I've got a single product page where after clicking on **Buy** button product is added to cart with variation data in POST query (wc-ajax: add_to_cart). In this case POST data looks like this:

```
woovr_variation_1465: on
woovr_variation_1465: on
attribute_%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8a%d0%b5%d0%bc: 2 x 1000 ml + 500 ml
quantity: 1
(empty)
product_id: 1467
variation_id: 1467
```

Button that is clicked on in this case:

```html
<button type="submit" class="single_add_to_cart_button button alt added">Buy</button>
```

And there are also some hidden inputs near with variation data etc:

```html
<input type="hidden" name="add-to-cart" value="1465">
<input type="hidden" name="product_id" value="1465">
<input type="hidden" name="variation_id" class="variation_id" value="1467">
```

So, after all everything is working great, product is added to cart and if no variation selected it is added with default variation id.

But on my main page, products are generated customly. And same wc-ajax: add_to_cart method has little less POST data:

```
product_sku: 
product_id: 1465
quantity: 1
```

Button itself:

```html
<a href="?add-to-cart=1465" data-quantity="1" class="product-add-to-cart product_type_simple add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart added" data-product_id="1465" data-product_sku="" aria-label="Add to label" rel="nofollow">
```

In this case product is added to cart without any variation. 
I need to repeat same behaviour in 2nd case as it works in 1st case i wrote about in the beggining of the post. In other words how do i generate same hidden input fields and add product to cart with variation id ?

Comment: i looked at code for <a href="?add-to-cart"... button and it gathers all data-* fields in the link to form POST data, so i tried adding data-variation_id - but got no result :(

Comment: Can you find and add the PHP code related to the button. It seems that a small tweek needed to pull the variation ID and not the product Id.